# Photo links not working in my Shared Google Sheet

Tags: photo

When I click on the photo link I cannot see the photo and get a 404 Error Message.
I've opened the spreadsheet on various devices...Chromebook, iPhone, Mac Air.
I've tried accessing the sheets via 2 different Gmail accounts.